# Cambio PHP7 Each me da warning

Tags: php, php7, foreach

Hola he heredado un web en php, al cambiar al PHP7, me sale:

```
Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object
```

Quiero pintar una tabla con los horarios por cada día semana. Cuando tiene datos el valor pasado me pinta bien el horario. Pero desde el cambio de PHP7, cuando no hay ningún valor antes me lo dejaba en blanco y ahora me da el Warning. Hace días que estoy dando vueltas y no hay manera de encontrar la solución.

```
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++ ){   // paso por 5 dias laborables
   ?>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <?php
    while  (list ($dia, $valor)= each($setmana[$i])) {
                                    ?>

                    <p id="<?=$valor['lloc']?>">
                        <?=$valor['hores']?> <br />
                       <?php

               switch($valor['lloc']){

                           case 'CTE':  $text = "1 - Barcelona";
                               $llegenda_cte = 1;
                             break;
                   case 'FCJ':  $text = "2 - Madrid";
                               $llegenda_ccat = 1;
                             break;
                   case 'FCEP':  $text = "3 - Bilbao";
                               $llegenda_fcep = 1;  
                             break;     
                   case 'SBP':  $text = "4 - Sevilla";
                               $llegenda_sbp = 1;
                             break;
                           case ' ': $text= " ";
                              $llegenda_null=1;
                               break;
                 }          
        ?>
                        <small><?=$text?></small></p>
     <?php
      }
    ?>
         </td>
     <?php
            }
                        ?>
```

Comment: `$setmana` es aquella variable que contiene el resultado de la consulta a base de datos?

Comment: Usas MySQL? Si es así debes cambiar todas las instrucciones del tipo mysql_xxx por mysqli_xxx porque en PHP7 en lo que respecta a MySQL su extensión original está obsoleta, sólo Mysqli y PDO son válidos. Más información aquí: [mysql_connect eliminado](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: Es correcto lo que hace PHP 7, de ese modo te ayuda a tener que **controlar** tu código. **Antes de pasar/usar la variable deberías verificar precisamente si no está vacía o es nula**. Anteriormente PHP era demasiado permisivo en cosas de ese tipo, por lo que pululan los ejemplos de código que escapan a un control estricto del programador. Desde la versión 7 PHP se ha vuelto más restrictivo, y me parece correcto que así sea. La solución aquí no es otra que **controlar tus variables** y usarlas solamente cuando tengan datos.

Comment: muestranos un ejemplo de la estructura de `$setmana`. Por otro lado, `each` está obsoleto, debieras usar un `foreach`. Finalmente, como dice @A.Cedano , debieras poner un cortocircuito antes del while, de la forma `if(!is_array($setmana[$i])) {  continue; }`

Comment: Hola, he puesto el cortocircuito antes del "while" y me ha funcionado perfectamente. Ahora ya no me da el "warning". Muchas gracias me habéis sacado del apuro.